# Remove fatures with low Gini importance score to improve accuracy of Random forest

Tags: python, random-forest, scikit-learn, accuracy, gini

For a research project on a networking related subject, I am training and testing a Random forest model with a data set that contains 20 features.
Initially, I obtained a baseline accuracy of around 77%.

In order to improve the accuracy, I obtained the Gini importance scores of all the 20 features and systematically dropped the features with lower scores from the training set.
This let me obtain a Random forest model with an accuracy of 90+%.

**My question**: Is this an acceptable method? Or is there another approach that can be used in place of this, which is more acceptable in the research community?

If it is acceptable, what do I need to show that it is a valid method?

PS: I tried several other methods like PCA, but they were less successful.

Comment: Are the 77% and 90% accuracies OOB scores?

Comment: No, this is the accuracy I obtained for the testing data. I trained the model with data set A and tested with data set B, which are completely different from each other

Comment: This can be done in an acceptable way, but it depends on how you did it. Can you describe what you did in more detail? Can you explain what systematically dropping features means?

Comment: I trained a RF model with all 20 features included and obtained the their gini score. Then I dropped each feature one by one from the data set, starting with the one with the lowest gini score, until I got an acceptable accuracy (90+%).

Comment: Could be that you managed to improve the learning, could also be that you overfitted the test set. It would have been better if you did this on your training set (using CV or a validation set).